# Azure --- The service is unavailable

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have several ASP.NET web apps running on an S1 instance. I also have a WordPress site running as well. They were all working fine. Suddenly I am getting "The service is unavailable" for every one of my web sites. (I have other site on the free F1 tier that are working fine.)

Has anyone else experienced this? Is this normal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this error was due to a service outage (as mentioned by OP in comments under an answer).

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you've achieved your free quota. Check if the other web site are running in the same subscription, because as long as I know, when you reach the free quotas, all of your web sites will stop.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/bandwidth-quota-changes-to-the-free-offer-of-azure-app-service/

Comment: No, that's not it. Separate subscriptions, etc.

Comment: @Fernando Did you check your dashboard? Are you receiving errors?

Comment: There are no quotas for S1 (Standard) instances, so it's not likely to be the issue.

Comment: I've checked the dashboard... now the Azure service map has an informational notice in the central region... "An alert for App Service \ Web App is being investigated. More information will be provided as it is known. "

Comment: it's azure's issue. We had the same issue today. We won't be able to know what caused it since they normally wont disclose the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

While Thiago's answer isn't directly correct for web apps running on an S1 instance, his answer is helpful for those on F1 instances.

The included bandwidth on F1 instances have a daily quota of 165 MB per day across all Web Apps (10 Max) per region. This is summed up to be 5GB of bandwidth per month per region. This quota is enforced on a daily basis and your Web Apps will be suspended for the reminder of the day if met.

[Azure Subscription Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits)